# Prolog: Simple program outputting solutions

Tags: prolog

I've got a predicate taking a single argument.  When there is a solution, this single argument should equal some other argument I have (I have a predicate that goes from one argument to three).

I can print the solution easily to see that the algorithm works.  However, I just get `false`/`no` when the program runs.  I think this is something to do with me giving the program a variable and asking it to return the same variable but altered by the program's execution.  I've never had this situation before.

Any ideas guys?

If anyone as any suggestions about the code as a whole then I would welcome comments about that too.

Thanks very much and happy new year :).

```
% Eulers totient function 
phi( M ) :-
    phi( 0, 0, M ).    
phi( Count, Inter, M ) :-
    Count = M,
    print(Inter),
    M is Inter.
phi( Count, Inter, M ) :-
    Count \= M,
    coprime( Count, M ),
    InterNew is Inter + 1,
    CountNew is Count + 1, 
    phi( CountNew, InterNew, M ).
phi( Count, Inter, M ) :-
    Count \= M,
    \+ coprime( Count, M ),
    CountNew is Count + 1,
    phi( CountNew, Inter, M ).
```

UPDATE: This problem is one of the '99 Prolog problems' at : http://sites.google.com/site/prologsite/prolog-problems/2 and it's question 2.09.

UPDATE: coprime/2 predicate was asked for:

```
% coprime is defined as two integers having a gcd of 1  
coprime( X, Y ) :-
    gcd( X, Y, 1 ).
```

which uses gcd predicate:

```
% calculating the greatest common divisor of two numbers
% recursive version of Euclidian algorithm
gcd( G, 0, G ).
gcd( Lo, Hi, G ) :-
    Hi \= 0,
    Inter is Lo mod Hi,
    gcd( Hi, Inter, G ).
```

Comment: Could you post the coprime predicate?

Comment: What is `phi/1` supposed to do? Euler's totient function can't be implemented as a single-argument predicate...

Comment: @larsmans: can too - you could use a compound term like N-Phi as single argument, of course that would be nonsensical but still...

Comment: Oh wait, the OP prints the totient in `phi/3`, I hadn't noticed that.

Comment: @Little Bobby Tables: I've added coprime predicate as requested

Comment: @larsman: I've added a link to the description of the problem

Comment: @imperial, side note: in SWI-Prolog you can use `coprime(A,B) :- 1 is gcd(A,B).`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `false`/`no` answer results from the call `M is Inter`, which tries to establish equality between the totient `Inter` and the input number `M`. Since φ(*n*) is never equal to *n* except when *n* = 1, this almost always fails.

You may have intended to assign the value of `Inter` to `M`, but this impossible because `M` is always bound.